# Integrating Poisson kernel with bounded function

Tags: real-analysis

I know three facts about Poisson kernel $P_r$:

1. $P_r(\theta) \ge 0, $ for all $\theta$,
2. $$\lim_{r \to 1^-} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int \limits_{[-\pi, \pi]\setminus[-\epsilon, \epsilon]} P_r(t) dt = 0,$$
3. $$\lim_{r \to 1^-} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int \limits_{[-\epsilon, \epsilon]} P_r(t) dt = 1.$$

Now let's consider $\varphi: [-\pi, \pi] \mapsto \mathbb{C}$. The function is bounded and moreover $\varphi$ is continuous at $0$. I would like to show that 
$$\lim \limits_{r \to 1^-} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} \varphi(t) P_r(t) dt = \varphi(0)$$
knowing the facts above. I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: It will be helpful to use

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi P_r(t) \,dt = 1$$

for $0\le r <1.$ Then you'll have

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int \limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} \varphi(t) P_r(t)\, dt- \varphi(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\varphi(t) - \varphi(0))P_r(t)\,dt.$$

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful. Now we should divide our interval shouldn't we? How can we show that the integral is zero on the part without $0$? I don't know how to handle the part with $\varphi$.

Comment: I dare guess you've seen this kind of argument before.